# Use Python in C

Tags: python, c, gcc

I need to use features that are only available in Python for a program written in C. I found several sources to help me but just [one of them](http://sametmax.com/embeder-python-dans-du-c-ou-c/) gives me the command to compile the code:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 prog.c -lpython2.7 -o prog -Wall  && ./prog
```

I had to change it to

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.4 prog.c -lpython3.4 -o prog -Wall  && ./prog
```

but the compiler returns:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's one of the first times I have used `gcc` so I really don't understand what to do even when I look at examples.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: You probably need to install the relevant package for your system. You may want to start by taking a look at the [relevant section of the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

Comment: I did but I don't understand why it explains I have to use the command it gives to find the right flags when another one seems to have managed to compile his code without them.

Comment: If you could say what features you want to use, there might be other ways (e.g. existing C data structure libraries) to access those features that would be easier than accessing the Python libraries from C.

Comment: Try running `ldconfig` as superuser, while installing some C libraries I found necessary to call that before being able to use `-l`

Comment: I would like to use a PIR motion sensor. I found [this library](http://wiringpi.com/) but I gave up because I haven't found how to use it with this sensor (it recognizes the sensor is connected but I can't get any information from it) So, I chose to try an easier way with [a code](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/parent-detector/worksheet/)  given by the Raspbery Foundation

Comment: Thanks, I use ldconfig -p and I realized that the library name was "python3.4m" and not "python3.4".

Comment: @BaptisteDebes Good! I believe that if you run `ldconfig` without arguments it will alias `python3.4m` to just `python3.4`, so you can use the standard name when linking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to interface C and Python using Cython?

The manual can be found here: https://python.g-node.org/python-summerschool-2011/_media/materials/cython/cython-slides.pdf

In section 4.10 it talks briefly about interfacing python and C. My thoughts are that you could call your C code from Cython, that way you have complete and direct access to the Python features that you want to use.

Here's more on interfacing with external C code:

http://cython-docs2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html

Answer (score 0):

Run `ldconfig` as the root user, to rebuild the cache and update the symbolic links:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

> **ldconfig** creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file */etc/ld.so.conf*, and in the trusted directories (*/lib* and */usr/lib*). The cache is used by the run-time linker, *ld.so* or *ld-linux.so*. **ldconfig** checks the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.
>
> [...]

Source: [`man ldconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)

If that doesn't work, use the `-p` option and find the name of the Python library:

```
ldconfig -p | grep python
```

And unless you have a specific reason otherwise, use the one with the smallest filename.

> `-p`
>
> Print the lists of directories and candidate libraries stored in the current cache.